# Node js how to get list of keys pressed

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdin

I'm writing a command line app using Node js. I'm trying to get keypresses from stdin. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
const readline = require('readline');

readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);

process.stdin.on('keypress', (str, key) => {
  console.log(str)
  console.log(key)
})
```

This works pretty well. It gets all letters and I can see if some modifiers were pressed such as control/shift. But it doesn't register some key combinations like shift+alt+up. I would like a method to just get a list of keys pressed so I can parse combos like that.

Also, some key combos are registered as ansi escape sequences. For example:

```
// ctrl+a
{ sequence: '\x01', name: 'a', ctrl: true, meta: false, shift: false }

// ctrl+h
{
  sequence: '\b',
  name: 'backspace',
  ctrl: false,
  meta: false,
  shift: false
}
```

Here ctrl+a is registered as 'a' with control pressed, but ctrl+h is registered as backspace. In this case I'd like a way to see if ctrl+h was pressed.

Comment: Do you get 3 separate events when `shift+alt+up` is pressed? Or do you get no event at all?

Comment: No event at all.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Reproducing this in visual studio code (arch distro), the code is logging `ctrl+h` and `ctrl alt up` without a problem (it shows the sequence in the `sequence` field). If this is an OS specific issue you may want to file a bug in the nodejs repo and use another library possibly.

Comment: Im running Windows 10. Out of curiosity, does `shift alt up/down` log for you?

Answer (score 0):

The stdin is based on byte streams, so it only responds to bytes. Whether the corresponding keystroke will input bytes depends on a higher layer, such as the operating system. If you want to detect keystrokes, you have to use proprietary APIs from the higher layer.